# Stopping a link from returning to the top

Tags: hyperlink

I've got an image that says "Add to Cart" and when it is clicked, jQuery makes a div show up saying added to cart successfully. The problem is, because I need it to be a link for the rollover for the picture to work, it links to the top of the page when clicked (

```
<div class="producttext"> Body Snatcher <!-- product name text --> <div class="pricetag"><img src="pricetags/1499.png" width="113" height="150" /> </div></div> <!-- pricetag, ending both the pricetag and text div -->
  <div class="addtocart"><a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('cart','','cart-rollover.png',1)"><img onclick="document.getElementById('addedcartbg').style.display = 'block'" src="cart.png" width="200" height="80" id="cart" /></a> <br /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the href to "javascript:;" so it doesn't jump to the named/empty (so top) anchor.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess at this, as I can't see the code involved in the functions you are using here. Generally, when I use a function call and do not want any change to the page that it is called from, I will simply add 'return false;' as the last line of the function.

However, if you have data that you want returned from the function, then you may need to place the values the function returns in a globally declared variables before you return false from the function.
As an example, in your functions shown...

```
function MM_swapImgRestore() {
  ...do my processing here;
  my_global_variable_1 = (value you want returned from this function)
  return false;
}

functionMM_swapImage('cart','','cart-rollover.png',1) {
  ...do my processing here;
  my_global_variable_2 = (value you want returned from this function)
  return false;
}
```

For an anchor tag, you can do the same thing as such...

```
<a href="javascript:return false;"
   onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"
   onmouseover="MM_swapImage('cart','','cart-rollover.png',1)">
<img onclick="document.getElementById('addedcartbg').style.display='block'"
     src="cart.png" width="200" height="80" id="cart" />
</a>
```

Further, I would add the onclick event to the anchor instead of the image, even though
HTML5 allows javascript handlers on ALL tags.

```
<a href="javascript:return false;"
   onclick="document.getElementById('addedcartbg').style.display='block'"
   onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"
   onmouseover="MM_swapImage('cart','','cart-rollover.png',1)">
<img src="cart.png" width="200" height="80" id="cart" />
</a>
```

Here is an example I put up for you at jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Ephiphany/bRF7t/